# Copying files to new folder based on string within filename

Tags: python

I have a list of files which looks like this:

```
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band1.tif
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band2.tif
LT50300281984137PAC00_sr_band3.tif

LT50300281985137PAC00_sr_band1.tif
LT50300281985137PAC00_sr_band2.tif
LT50300281985137PAC00_sr_band3.tif
```

I have folders created titled `_1984_` and `_1985_` and I want to send all files which contain those respective strings (well just 1984 and 1985 with out the _ on the ends) to the corresponding folder.  I have years from 1984-2011 so if possible I would like to do this with some sort of loop.  Right now I have the files in a list and I am pulling out individual years and saving them to individual folders with this code:

```
import arcpy, os, shutil
#directory where .tif files are stored
in_raster='F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\just_bands'
#directory where files are copied
out_raster='F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\Years\_1984_'
#pull out year of interest as wildcard
list1=arcpy.ListRasters("*1984*")

for raster in list1:
     source_path = os.path.join(in_raster, raster)
     out_path=os.path.join(out_raster,raster)
     shutil.copy(source_path, out_path)
print ('Done Processing')
```

I would really like to automate this for all years though and this is where I am stuck.  So once all files containing `1984` are copied to appropriate folder, the same is done for `1985` and so on.

Edit:

This code:

```
import os, shutil, glob
    for fpath in glob.glob('F:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\hank_masked\just_bands/*.tif'):  # this returns a list of the CURRENT contents. Therefore, there is no need to sanitize for the directories that we will later create
        year = os.path.basename(fpath)[9:13]
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.path.getcwd(), year)):
            os.mkdir(year)
        shutil.move(fpath, year)
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getcwd'
```

Comment: Replace `os.path.getcwd()` with `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have all these files in one directory, and you want to create all your folders in the same directory. Then, this should do it:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

outputDir = os.getcwd()

for fpath in glob.glob('*.tif'):  # this returns a list of the CURRENT contents. Therefore, there is no need to sanitize for the directories that we will later create
    year = os.path.basename(fpath)[9:13]
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(outputDir, year)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(outputDir, year))
    shutil.move(fpath, os.path.join(outputDir, year))
```

Comment: This returns the error, `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getcwd'`.

Comment: fixed based on above comment.  One thing, this saves all the files and folders to the directory where my `.py` code is being executed.  I'm new to using `os` in python, is there an easy way to change output directory?